# Exclude Element from .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I have to remove a specific element (button with #add_phone) from .html() of jquery.

So here's the thing. At first there are field(phone number) + select(phone type) + button(#add_phone), and all three are enclosed in div as a container. And when I click the button, it will recreate that through .html().
The JS is as follows:

```
$('#add_phone').click(function() {
    $('div.multiple_number:last').after('<div id="phone_div_id' + phone_div_id + '" class="multiple_number">'+ $('div.multiple_number').html() +'</div>');
    ...
    //append a remove [-] button, etc...     
});
```

and here's the html:

```
<div class="multiple_number" id="phone_div_id0">
    <label>Phone Number(s):</label>
    <input name="phone" id="phone[]" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
    <select name="phone_type[]" id="phone_type">
        <option value="1">Mobile</option>
        <option value="2">Home</option>
        <option Value="3">Office</option>
        <option Value="3">Fax</option>          
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="add_phone" class="add_phone_class" id="add_phone" value="ADD MORE" />
</div>
```

So in effect, I am creating multiple phone numbers for a form. But, here's the problem. Inside is an input type="button" (`#add_phone` button). And I would want to exclude it from .html().

**I have tried:**

```
$('div.multiple_number:not(#add_phone)').html()
$('div.multiple_number:not(input#add_phone)').html()
$('div.multiple_number:not(#add_phone)').not(#add_phone).html()
$('div.multiple_number:not(#add_phone)').not(input#add_phone).html()
```

And the class name counterpart instead of using id name. I wouldn't also want to place the #add_phone button outside the div, for aesthetics reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit unclear about what you're looking for, but I assume that when the `#add_phone` button is clicked, you want the form to be duplicated and added below it with the exception of the `#add_phone` button itself.

Working off that assumption, the following should work

```
$('#add_phone').click(function() {
    var numberForms = $('div.multiple_number');
    var newNumberForm = numberForms.eq(0).clone(true);
    newNumberForm.find('#add_phone').remove();
    newNumberForm.attr('id', 'phone_div_id' + numberForms.length);
    numberForms.last().after(newNumberForm);
});
```

Here's a [live jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F67Ap/) to show it working.

Your initial attempts didn't work for a few reasons. The main one being that `:not()` selector and `.not`() methods only operate on the element being selected. It doesn't filter based on child elements. Those methods would only work if the element you were selecting `<div class="multiple_number" />` also had the ID `add_phone`.

Also, it is not recommended to use `.html()` as a way of cloning methods. Using string manipulation as an alternative to direct DOM manipulation can cause problems later on. Using `.html()` will force you to have to re-bind event handlers to the newly created DOM elements. The strategy I've provided above should be more future-proof, since it will also clone event handlers for any elements being copied. There are also cases where certain browsers will not replicate the original elements exactly when calling `.html()`, which is another reason to avoid it unless you have a specific reason for serializing your DOM elements as a string.

Comment: You're a genius. You got to answer why `not` doesn't work in my case plus you got a better solution. Not to mention, yours is more readable. And oh...is that why I had to use .on() or .live() for those created by my .html() as .click() can't find the newly created DOM? With yours I could now use .click() to find #remove_phone button if I place one on each newly created phone input? Thanks.

Comment: @Fred You're correct, that's why you would have to use `.on()` or `.live()` (though `.on()` is the preferred method). You should be able to use `.click()` if you want to for newly created inputs as long as you use `.clone(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
var innerHTML = $("div.multiple_number").html()
                .replace($("div.multiple_number input#add_phone").html(), "");
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a very good workaround...and I thought that it would work, but it didn't. Still the same result, the #add_phone button still gets included in the succeeding div.multiple_number

Comment: This wouldn't work because `.html()` only serializes the *children* of the matched element. Since there are no children on an `<input />` element, the call to `.html()` would return an empty string.